# What is the most general Serializable collection?

Tags: scala, collections, abstract, serializable

AFAIK, `GenTraversableOnce` is the most general collection type, so I should prefer it over more specific collection types in APIs. However, I don't think is a subtype of `Serializable`.

If I have

```
case class(name: String, items: TYPE) extends Serializable
```

what should `TYPE` be in order to be the most general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, only concrete classes like `List` extend `Serializable` in the collections API. However, you can use the compound type `GenTraversableOnce[_] with Serializable`:

```
case class(name: String, items: GenTraversableOnce[_] with Serializable) extends Serializable
```

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't even be surprised Scala would let you do that :P

Comment: I think that would be an intersection type, not a structural type. A structural type looks more like `def x:AbstractType{ def someMethod: OtherType }`

Comment: @acjay You're right, it's not a structural type. I found [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/110), which seems to suggest the term is compound type, though I think intersection type might be the name in other languages.

Comment: They use "intersection type" up at the top of that link -- "In Scala this can be expressed with the help of compound types, which are intersections of object types." So I think it would be accurate to say that save for the value types, it's pretty much synonymous here. Mostly, I've seen the *intersection type* terminology, but thanks for sharing, because it'll be good to know there's another term for the concept.